# .NET Core 2.2 Assembly System.Windows.Forms missing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to migrate my project in .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET Core 2.2. But I have an error in my program execution.

My project wants to load a .dll with the `Assembly` class, it's working fine with .NET Framework 4.0 but not with .NET Core 2.2. It's throwing a n exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

```
using System.Reflection; // Assembly class

var pathToDll = "../../../../";
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToDll);

var callingProgObject = asm.GetType("RandomType.CallingProg");
MethodInfo method = callingProgObject.GetMethod("MethodInDll");

var input = new InputForDll();
method.Invoke(callingProgObject, new object[] {input}); // <-------- error
```

I need to import one package compatible for .NET Core 2.2 similar to `System.Windows.Forms` of .NET Framework 4.0?

My NuGet packages installed in Solution:

[image: My NuGet packages installed in Solution]

*Not duplicate of [How to use System.Windows.Forms in .NET Core class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460253/how-to-use-system-windows-forms-in-net-core-class-library)*

Comment: Did you replace the real values with RandomType and MethodInDll  ? Because they are rather crucial here. And what part of your code is calling this (and why) ?

Comment: Winforms isn't supported in .NET Core 2.2. It might be supported in .NET Core 3 though. [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/)

Comment: Primary focus for .netcore was to make porting to Linux and macOS easy.  That can't work for Winforms, those OSes are far too different.  I haven't see a lot of praise for Mono's attempt to do this.  Consider Xamarin if you need a GUI that runs on .netcore. Or wait until .netcore 3 gets stable, if porting is not important, that will take a while. No rush, .netframework is just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Windows Forms (or WPF) for .NET Core.

What you want is not possible

<sup>(but might be possible with a defined subset of .NET Core with the next major version)</sup>

If you list your requirements, maybe people can suggest another way to do it, but it won't be Windows Forms.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to run WinForms, it's obviously an ASP.NET Core project. With some obscure component still wanting to use something from Windows.Forms, like maybe `Color` or `Rect`

Comment: Then why did you accept this answer?  That sends the wrong message.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the Windows.Forms is not supported on .NET core.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779236/4743730) for alternate ways of creating GUI in .NET core.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

to your .csproj file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).