# Service not calling OnShutdown() when windows shuts down

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-2.2

I have .net core console application, which is hosted as windows service.
I want to catch an event if the user logs off/shutdown the computer.

I have found ways to catch this event in .net framework ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) & [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents?view=netframework-4.8)).
But I cant figure out how to achieve this in .net core.

To create service I am using "ServiceBase" class. Sample code is as given below:

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    readonly string LogPath = "D:\\TestAppService.txt";

    #region Constructors
    public MyService()
    {
        this.CanShutdown = true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Protected Functions
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //your code here

        // call the base class so it has a chance
        // to perform any work it needs to
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //your code here

        // Call the base class 
        base.OnStop();
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(LogPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("shutdown == true");
        }

        //your code here
        base.OnShutdown();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The OnStop and OnStart methods are being called.
but when I shutdown the computer my OnShutdown method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

According to [aspisof.net](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding#declarations), you should be able to use the SessionEnding API. This is because it is listed as being exposed in the [windows Compatibility Pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814807.aspx) - available on NuGet [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility).

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack) on learn.microsoft.com shows how you can include it in a .NET Core application.

---

**tl;dr**

1. Add the NuGet package
2. Target Windows only

---

One thing to note: this was originally designed to be a temporary fix for porting Windows specific .NET code over to .NET Core.

The more accepted way to implement Windows only features is to move as much code to [.NET Standard libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) as possible, and to use [conditional compilation directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) to include platform specific code when building for that platform.

Comment: thanks for the help. But Console applications(Hosted as windows service) do not raise the SessionEnding event. In a Windows service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump has been started manually, this event will not be raised.
The actual problem is in.NET Core 2.2 Assembly System.Windows.Forms missing as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986985/net-core-2-2-assembly-system-windows-forms-missing)

Comment: I have updated my question could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

By design dotnet core is not "friendly" with platform specific stuff
(like listening to log off event seems to me).

The solution I use in one of Windows-hosted services is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646827/on-exit-for-a-console-application).

When application domain is forced to close by operating system on shutdown - there is a room for using AppDomain event handlers.