# Developed a small app under winforms can I develop it under linux?

Tags: c#, linux, gecko

I have developed a small .Net WinForms app on Visual Studio 2017 using C#. 
I used Gecko for that project.

It is basically an app that would open a full screen webpage using Gecko web browser object.

Now I want to run the same app, also using Gecko under Linux, hence a simple Gecko web browser object to open up the webpage, embedded into an app under Linux.

My question is how can I achieve this?

Are there any tools to compile the same project for Linux? Or is it better to start from scratch under Linux IDE? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a lot of developments with. Net core and Linux check this thread [Is it possible to make desktop GUI application in .NET core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649976/is-it-possible-to-make-desktop-gui-application-in-net-core/39650336)

Answer (score 0):

I came a cross this website that automatically does what I want, it turns a website to an application under windows/linux/macos.

https://www.todesktop.com/

If those guys can automate it, this means it's doable.
I have shifted my project's focus from Gecko to Chromium using CefSharp though.